# Why am I getting an error with UIImageRepresentation with 2 different strings?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, uiimageview

So when I only have the myImageView1 in its fine but why is it giving me an error when I add myImageView2 in next to it separated by a comma. The error is at the uploadData part. How do I fix this?

```
@IBAction func upload(_ sender: Any) {


    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image.png")
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView1.image!){

        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                return
            }


            else {
                let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Download URL": (downloadURL), "Download URL 2": (downloadURL2)])


            }
```

Comment: It's difficult for us to diagnose your code if you don't include the code that doesn't work. You need to update your post to include the broken code, as well as any relevant error messages you're receiving, and how you've already tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the declaration of `UIImagePNGRepresentation`:

```
func UIImagePNGRepresentation(_ image: UIImage) -> Data?
```

This function only takes one argument. You will need to get their data separately and find a way to combine them into one `Data` object.